# Не получается получить имя файла в gtkmm (виджет FileChooserButton)

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm3

```
Gtk::FileChooserButton *chooserButton = nullptr;
std::string idChooserButton = commonArray[b]["id"];
builder->get_widget(idChooserButton, chooserButton);
Php::call("var_dump",chooserButton);
if (strcmp(commonArray[b]["action"], "click") == 0) {
    Php::Value callback = commonArray[b]["callback"];
    chooserButton->signal_selection_changed().connect(
            sigc::bind<Php::Value,Php::Value>(
                    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ParserGtk::callbacks),
                    callback,
                    chooserButton->get_filename()
            )
    );
}
```

Это мой код, когда я выбираю файл срабатывает callback, но функция `get_filename` возвращает пустую строку ""

Comment: Что-то не вижу, где `chooserButton` принимает какое-то не нулевое значение.

Comment: @alexolut в смысле?

Comment: Чему равно `chooserButton` во время вызова?

Comment: @alexolut 0x555555ea4eb0 вроде вот этому если правильно сдампил

Comment: А где оно устанавливается? в `get_widget` что ли по ссылке?

Comment: да в `get_widget` и `signal` тоже срабатывает тут после изменения выбраного файла. пробывал так же через `signal_file_set`. Т.е. после того как фаил выбран `chooserButton->get_filename` возвращает пустотту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, в моём случае я пытался вызвать `get_filename` во время выполнения сигнала. Надо просто вызвать `get_filename` в callback функции. В общем код преобрёл следующий вид:

```
 chooserButton->signal_file_set().connect(
                sigc::bind<Php::Value,Gtk::FileChooserButton*>(
                        sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ParserGtk::chooserButtonCallback),
                        callbackChooser,
                        chooserButton
                )
        );
```

и callback функция

```
/**
 * choooser button special  callback
 * @param callback php callback function
 * @param chooserButton gtk filechooserbutton object
 */
void ParserGtk::chooserButtonCallback(Php::Value callback, Gtk::FileChooserButton *chooserButton) {
    Php::call("var_dump",chooserButton->get_filename());
    callback(chooserButton->get_filename());
}
```